# Prefix string to ALL generated table names - FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a simple way to prefix all generated table names with a string?

The convention

```
Table.Is(x => "Prefix" + x.EntityType.Name)
```

only works for Entity tables (doesn't function for join or subclass tables)

I can't seem to find a simple way to have every single table that nhibernate creates be prefixed with a specific string without first identifying all the cases that would create a table and specifying a rule per case.  Ew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you have to implement `IHasManyToManyConvention` and `IJoinedSubclassConvention` see

```
public class SubclassConvention : IJoinedSubclassConvention, IHasManyToManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IJoinedSubclassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table("Prefix" + instance.Type.Name);
    }

    public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table("Prefix" + instance.TableName);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have to implement a convention for each object that would create a table then?

The full list would be entities, subclasses, and many-to-many?

Comment: @MushinNoShin ... and value collections. i havent found any other way yet

Comment: Going to accept this as a "You can't do that in an overly simple way".  Unfortunate; I hate typing.

Comment: @OnurGazioğlu Sorry, you are right. I Made a copy paste error. It worked where i wrote it, but not when i copy it back. Testet with FNH 1.3